# NextJS when parsing emoji/spacial char build crash using "export" script

Tags: next.js, build

I have a simple NextJs app.

When I'm running the app on a localhost everything seems to work fine - The code complied successfully with no errors.

When I use this script: next build && next export
and browse to my local build, The browser load only my html file (without any css files),
and I received the following error:

1. The stylesheet https://my-app/_next/static/css/b5fa8f67lb08ea0a.css was not loaded because its MINE type, "text/html", is not "text/css"
2. Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

The code that causes the error:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Main = () => {
    return (
        <div>
          <iframe src="https://dummy-demo" 
             title="▶My Demo"
          />
        </div>
}
```

When I removed the "▶" char the error disappeared and the application complied successfully.

I would like to know the reasons for the error and any alternative ways to compile successfully "special" chars while using next build && next export scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to replace `▶` by it’s [numeric character reference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference): `&#9654;` ?

Comment: Yes - seems to work fine.

Is there is alternative use also for emojis?

Comment: Nice. For emoji, you can ask google `html code emoji + emojiiName`